# I am using apache shiro under camel and I cannot map groups to roles with ldap/active directory

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, shiro

I am using shiro with camel. I can authenticate an user with activedirectory (ldap) but I am not able to map user groups in roles to user permissions. And camel needs absolutely permissions to work.

Here is my config.ini:

```
[main]
authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy


activeDirectoryRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm
activeDirectoryRealm.systemUsername=cn=padl,cn=Users,dc=comune,dc=prato,dc=local
activeDirectoryRealm.systemPassword=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
activeDirectoryRealm.url = ldap://172.16.1.98:389
activeDirectoryRealm.groupRolesMap = "CN=menu_ufficiomobile_ania,OU=Menu,OU=Gruppi,OU=ComuneDiPrato,DC=comune,DC=prato,DC=local":"menu_ufficiomobile_ania"

securityManager.realms = $activeDirectoryRealm
[users]

test = test,menu_ufficiomobile_passicarrabili, menu_ufficiomobile_rubati,menu_ufficiomobile_ordinanze, menu_ufficiomobile_ztl, menu_ufficiomobile_cciaa,  menu_ufficiomobile_ania, menu_ufficiomobile_anagrafe, menu_ufficiomobile_mctc, menu_ufficiomobile_pra


[roles]

menu_ufficiomobile_anagrafe = prato:anagrafe
menu_ufficiomobile_mctc = prato:mctc
menu_ufficiomobile_pra = prato:pra
menu_ufficiomobile_ania = prato:ania
menu_ufficiomobile_cciaa = prato:cacomm
menu_ufficiomobile_ztl = prato:ztl
menu_ufficiomobile_ordinanze = prato:ordinanze
menu_ufficiomobile_rubati = prato:rubati
menu_ufficiomobile_passicarrabili = prato:permessi
```

My security injection code:

```
ShiroSecurityToken shiroSecurityToken = new ShiroSecurityToken(qr.getUserName(),qr.getPassword());
ShiroSecurityTokenInjector shiroSecurityTokenInjector = new ShiroSecurityTokenInjector(shiroSecurityToken, passPhrase);
arg0.getIn().setHeader("SHIRO_SECURITY_TOKEN", shiroSecurityTokenInjector.encrypt());
```

And the routing code that uses permissions:

```
from("seda:interrogaANIA").threads(1)
 .setHeader("db", constant(Database.ANIA)).policy(aniaS)
 .to("bean:interrogaANIA?method=interrogaBancaDati")
 .to("seda:prefilter");
```

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, a realm in shiro provides 3 things:

1. Authenticate users
2. Map users to roles
3. Map users to permissions

What it does not do is provide arbitrary role->permission mapping.  For this, you would need to set a RolePermissionResolver on your active directory realm.  Looking at the IniRealm (which is what gets created by the [users] and [roles] section in your ini file), there doesn't appear to be an easy way to use it as a RolePermissionResolver.  I was able to throw together an adapter class that should work reasonably well.

```
package org.apache.shiro.samples.web;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.shiro.authz.Permission;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.SimpleRole;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.permission.RolePermissionResolver;
import org.apache.shiro.config.Ini;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm;

public class IniRealmRolePermissionResolver implements RolePermissionResolver {
        private LocalIniRealm realm;

        public Collection<Permission> resolvePermissionsInRole(final String roleString) {
                final SimpleRole role = this.realm.getRole(roleString);
                return role == null ? Collections.<Permission>emptySet() : role.getPermissions();
        }

        public void setIni(final IniRealm ini) {
                this.realm = new LocalIniRealm();
                this.realm.setIni(ini.getIni());
                this.realm.init();
        }

        private static class LocalIniRealm extends IniRealm {
                @Override
                protected SimpleRole getRole(final String rolename) {
                        return super
                                        .getRole(rolename);
                }
        }
}
```

This should be usable with this addition to your ini file:

```
rolePermissionResolver = org.apache.shiro.samples.web.IniRealmRolePermissionResolver
rolePermissionResolver.ini = $iniRealm
activeDirectoryRealm.rolePermissionResolver = $rolePermissionResolver
```

If you don't really need the ini mapping, you can use the same concept, but greatly simplify things.

```
package org.apache.shiro.samples.web;

import org.apache.shiro.authz.Permission;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.permission.*;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SimpleRolePermissionResolver implements RolePermissionResolver, PermissionResolverAware {

    private PermissionResolver permissionResolver = new WildcardPermissionResolver();

    public void setPermissionResolver(PermissionResolver permissionResolver) {
        this.permissionResolver = permissionResolver;
    }

    public Collection<Permission> resolvePermissionsInRole(String roleString) {
        return Collections.<Permission>singleton(permissionResolver.resolvePermission(roleString));
    }
}
```

And then your ini configuration changes a bit as well:

```
rolePermissionResolver = org.apache.shiro.samples.web.SimpleRolePermissionResolver
activeDirectoryRealm.rolePermissionResolver = $rolePermissionResolver
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply I will use it for sure. Just a question: infact if I can choose I do not need arbitrary role/permission map. The user is in several groups and the group name is the role I want to use. But as far as I know in camel .policy() I can specify only a permission list and not a role list. am I right?

Comment: I don't really have any experience with camel, but from looking at the ShiroSecurityPolicy, it appears that yes, you can only specify permissions.  However, I have edited my answer to include an option for a SimpleRolePermissionResolver.  This will probably serve your purposes better.

Comment: Thank you again. I do not understand only a thing: with the new code above if user is in group X automatically (without .ini) it has also role X and it can use the permission of role X that I specify in the .ini?

Comment: I believe that what you are asking is addressed by activeDirectoryRealm.groupRolesMap.  But I could have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Now I understand perfectly your code and it should be included in official shiro examples or shiro source code. My missing piece was that, apparently, activedirectoryRealm has no concept of permissions but only groups that can be (optionally and non automatically) mapped to roles.

Comment: Worked like a charm with shiro, lift-shiro and IniRealmRolePermissionResolver when role permissions were set in shiro.ini. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!